# The grammar structure "love someone something"

Tags: sentence-structure, non-standard-english

It was in [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/o69TvQqyGdg). It is at 3 minute and 26 second. Here it goes:

> Interestingly King James hated smoking. He called it "a custom loathsome to the eye and hateful to the nose", but he **loved him** **some tax revenue**, and nothing sells like drugs.

It is understandable from the context that King James wanted to have more money, but is it grammatical to use the verb *love* this way?

Comment: Related at EL&U *[Reflexive love: where does “love me some …” come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92883)* It is associated with some Southern US and African-American dialects but non-standard.

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1364/bd03ba1f76d58c12438630901ea301ef741a.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**to love someone something is basically Southern American English.**

it means: to like or would like to have.

It's usually with would: I've love me some hot dogs. [I'd love to have or get some hotdogs]

Technical explanation: [non-argument datives](http://www.cssp.cnrs.fr/eiss7/horn-eiss7.pdf)

These are a feature of Southern American and Appalachian speech

Here are some I have made up:

I'm gonna marry me a pretty gal.

He's gonna get him a shotgun.

From the same paper cited above,here is a list of famous songs using this form:

> b. I’m gonna grab/catch me a freight train. (various songs)
>
> c. When
>   I was a young girl, I had me a cowboy
>
> (John Prine, “Angel From
>   Montgomery”)
>
> d. I had me a man in summertime/He had summer-colored
>   skin
>
> (Joni Mitchell, “Urge for Going”) e. Now the Union Central’s
>   pulling out and the orchids are in bloom,
>
> I’ve only got me one
>   shirt left and it smells of stale perfume. (Bob Dylan, “Up to Me”)

[[Joke: Not for nothin' did they give ol' Dylan the Nobel Priize.]]

Comment: This answer doesn't acknowledge the facetious and jocular nature of the quoted line. Or are you saying the speaker is mocking Southern American English?

Comment: I did not address that. For me, the grammar was important, rather than the style. Shall we just leave it at that?